# React Native - Justify Content not Working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I've been struggling with this all over my react-native app, so I set up a very simple example of it in codesandbox which you can view here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-star-5754q?file=/src/App.js

Within the View with the green background, all of the internal views are centered horizontally within their respective spaces as I would expect thanks to the "alignItems: center" style property. I would expect that I could also center them vertically within their spaces  by setting "justifyContent: center", but that doesn't seem to work for me.

Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not aligning the text within the individual Views. **Your example mistakenly aligns the inner View elements within the larger View element** rather than aligning the text.

To center-align the text vertically within *their Views* you just need to **add `justifyContent: "center"` to those individual three green Views.**

Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-kirch-n8one?file=/src/App.js:393-417

To further explain why you were experiencing the issue you did, see this screenshot with boxes outlining the space the elements were taking up on-screen:

[image: Boxes]

You can see the inner `View`s are only taking up the needed width of the `text` elements inside, but are using the max height available to them.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense, thank you. But then it leaves me with the question, why did my "alignItems" that I placed at the same level work just fine? Shouldn't that not affect the nested text either?

Comment: Good question! See my screenshot I just added in above with an outline of the individual `div`s. Hopefully that helps you see what is going on with the layout. In general keep in mind that horizontal space and vertical space are treated very differently.

Comment: Ahhh, now I get it. Since the view containing the text takes up the entire vertical space, centering that view vertically does absolutely nothing. Very helpful, thank you!